# Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by them

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have tried many ways like

```
var win = window.open("","_self");*/ 
win.close();
```

and like this

```
window.opener=null;
window.open('','_self');
window.close();
window.history.go(-1);
document.body.hide();
```

But not working.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try this, it works for me.

```js
try {
     window.opener = window;
     var win = window.open("","_self");
     win.close();
     top.close();
 } catch (e) {

 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution! It works perfectly for me. I was struggling with closing a window in Edge browser using JavaScript, and your code snippet did the trick. :)

Answer (score -1):

The script runs inside window.prototype, imported by the respective  call inside the html markup. Unless you import the script to gain access to the respective window,  like using a library, i don't think you can do it.